# UITableViewController's view added as subview to UIViewController crashes app

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have these two classes in my project:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

and

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController
@end
```

Within MainViewController.m, I am trying to do this:

```
TableViewController *tview = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" 
                                    bundle:nil];  
tview.tableView.dataSource = tview;
tview.tableView.delegate = tview;
[self.view addSubview: tview.view];
```

However, this is crashing with an:

```
-[MainViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb52dc90'
```

I don't understand why MainViewController is becoming the datasource/delegate for the TableViewController, when I already set the delegate/datasource in the init above.  I also tried to set TableViewController's delegate/datasource to self from within its viewDidLoad, but the MainViewController still keeps acting as the delegate/datasource, regardless.  I tried with the nib files hooked up and not hooked up, but no difference.

Ideally, I want the TableViewController to act as the delegate and datasource, and have its view added to MainViewController.  How can I get this done?

Thank you!

Note: Neither solution worked for some reason.  In the end, I recreated TableViewController as inheriting from UIViewController and set it as  and things went normally then.

Answer (score 0):

Where have you written the TableView delegate methods?? They should be inside your TableViewController Class and not inside the MainViewController Class.
Write the UITableView delegate methods inside the TableViewController Class.

Hope this will solve your problem...

Comment: The delegate and datasource methods are written in the TableViewController class.

Comment: You just remove the `tview.tableView.delegate = tview;
tview.tableView.dataSource = tview;` since the TableViewController is a UITableViewController class so you dont need to explicitly mention the delegate class.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set delegate and datasource to nil in dealloc method?

```
tview.tableView.delegate = nil;
tview.tableView.dataSource = nil;
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the dealloc method of the MainViewController or the TableViewController?

Comment: TableViewController I believe.